# Google oauth is responding with redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

My site is already live, example - https://www.example.io (with https)

[image]

[image]

I always get back this error

[image]

For some reason it is using HTTP although in the credentials i use https.

Btw this google API is already in production.

I'm not sure how to debug this. i tried http://localhost:3000 and it works perfectly for local development.

I'm using https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth with node.js

Answer (score 0):

It works after i added a slash at the end

```
https://example.com/auth/google/callback
```

to

```
 https://example.com/auth/google/callback/
```

I'm not sure though, but hope that this will help other people

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Solved it with replacing the url"/auth/google/callback" in the new GoogleStrategy with the full url: https://{my-domain}/auth/google/callback. for some reason google were looking for an http url and adding the full one with 'https' solved it.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.OAUTH2_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH2_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://{your-domain}/auth/google/callback"
  },
  async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
Your code goes here

});
```